# PHP8 PDO SQLite3 execute => fetch* => Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I like to use prepared Statements on SQL-calls to a SQLITE3 Database, so i have to use "exectue()" on statements. Fetching results stucks on error "*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool*".

```
try {
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
    
    // this works fine:
    $result = $db->query($SQL)->fetch(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    print_r($result);  // actually delivers 1 recordset

    // this not:
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($SQL);
    $result = $stmt->execute()->fetch(SQLITE3_ASSOC); // <= Error
    print_r($result);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $ret['error'] = $e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $ret['error'] = $e->getMessage();
}
die(json_encode($ret));
```

=> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool in..."

Same on fetchArray(). What's wrong with this code?

Comment: you shouldn't use SQLITE3 constants with PDO

Comment: Meanwhile i'm using
`$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

The return values of execute are only "true" or "false"

```
$stmt->execute()
$result = $stmt->fetch(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
```